# Which is Best for .net developer Umbraco or Sitecore

Tags: .net

I need to choose a CMS for wesbite developing with WCF services , can some one suggest which is best between Umbraco and Sitecore for easy integration with Visual Studio, debugging , quick learning, problem solving , forum support, hosting(dedicate server) etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umbraco. Use SiteCore if you need an Enterprise solution with lots of support options.

Comment: Thanks David , we shall choose Umbraco , I have seen the umbraco community is great and best for mid level organization.